# Wrong value Max function in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying max() and min() function on one column but its giving me wrong result.

The numbers are 1500,500,200,800 and 700.

When I query

```
select max(trip_total_catches_kg) 
from trips
```

it gives me result 800 where it should be 1500 and minimum gives me 1500.

Why is it giving me wrong results?

Comment: Is your column - while holding **numbers** - defined as a **string** (`varchar`) by any chance?? When you look at those **strings** - then `800` Is the "max" - since the number `8` at the first position is the **largest** of those characters.... This is what you get from using **the wrong datatype**, e.g. store everything as strings... If you have **numbers** - then **STORE THEM** as numbers in a **numeric datatype!** That's what those datatypes are for!

Comment: [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28663606/3208640) answer gives exactly what you want, I prefer to use `convert` if changing and modifying your data structure cause problem for you

Comment: @FarhangAmary'Ferhęg' so you prefer a column with defintion for  kilogram but should be a string ? well I doubt this is a complex IT system, more than a homework.. so maybe doing it right from beginning is the best way, dont you think so ;)

Comment: @MrSimpleMind I gave the answer only on base of your given data and  problem and as you see it works perfect for info and data you provided in the question, if you don't believe you can [see it here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/156c5/1), and of course it's better for any thing to be done in right and correct way from scratch and beginning, you didn't mentioned a complex IT system!!;) or kilogram;) or etc in question, I just provided a solution for your existing and current situation.

Answer (score 2):

As @marc_s mentioned in a comment, I would double-check that the type of the `trip_total_catches_kg` column is numeric (`integer`), instead of string (`varchar(255)`).

The behavior you describe would make sense if the column was a string type, as @marc_s said:

> `800` Is the "max" - since the number `8` at the first position is the **largest** of those characters

Answer (score 1):

as @marc_s commented...
It is because of the column type, which is char / varchar and not integer.

here is a sqlfiddle as a demo.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ab63/1

Convert your column to a integer instead.

> alter table trips modify trip_total_catches_kg int;

Answer (score 1):

perhaps the type of values are `varchar`, convert them to `integer` then get `max` or `min` of them:

```
SELECT MAX(CONVERT(trip_total_catches_kg,UNSIGNED INTEGER))
FROM trips;
```

Answer (score 1):

The most terse answer:

```
select max(0 + trip_total_catches_kg) from trips;
```